# BeforeDestroy does not trigger if I change the url

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working on a project using VueJS and Laravel where, if a user is on a certain page, it changes the value of a certain table to true. I do this in the mounted section.

When I leave the page I would like to update that record to change that value to false. I am able to do this with the beforeDestroy hook, but only if I click on a link or hit the back button. Meaning, it changes the value back to false when either of these two are done. However, it does not trigger if I change the url. For example it will not trigger if i go from www.trivia.test/game to www.youtube.com (or wherever).

Here is my mounted and my beforeDestroy hooks:

Mounted:

```
mounted() {
        this.params = this.$route.params;
        this.fetchData(this.params);

        //changes the value to true
        axios.post('/api/game/' + this.params.id + '/play', {
            _method: 'patch'
        })
            .then(response => {
                // console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    },
```

beforeDestroy():

```
beforeDestroy() {

        //changes the value to false
        axios.post('/api/game/' + this.game.id + '/gameOver', {
            _method: 'patch'
        })
            .then(response => {
                // console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    },
```

How can I make this trigger when a person leaves the page no matter what?

Comment: you can achieve this with a simple alert box that say, are you sure you want to leave this page? that's how almost all site handle this.    U can use the window function to achieve this. `window.onbeforeunload`